# Compiling JSPs is very slow while uploading on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, jsp, compilation, gae-eclipse-plugin

while uploading App Engine Application to server, GAE upload is very slow and gets stuck at "Compiling JSP". I have seen a bug for the same here - http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=4222, but could not find a solution.

I have many JSP files. When I cut down the number of jsp files to 10, the files get uploaded in 10-15 mins ... but when I increase the number to 50, there seems to be a lot of delay (in hours).

It used to work fine with GAE 1.4.2. The issue is seen on the latest version GAE 1.6.2.1

Is there a workable solution/fix/workaround for this?

Comment: This issue is fixed. It was a configuration issue, where some of the old jars were left behind while upgrading gae from 1.4.2 to 1.6.2.1

Comment: How did you clean the jars? Are you talking about GAE SDK Jars? Or your own? I have the same problem with GAE 1.9.14